# NTLM Authentication on a mobile device

Tags: windows, authentication, native, ntlm, ntlm-authentication

I am developing an Ionic 5 + Angular 11 mobile application as a mobile interface for an existing Windows REST Server. The server is using NTLM Authentication, which of course is native to a browser and many browsers support this type of authentication, automatically prompting the user to enter the credentials upon the first HTTP request to that server.

I tried deploying to an android device today and did not manage to find any way to use the same authentication on the mobile device. I was thinking perhaps it would be helpful to create an HTTP interceptor that passes the authentication headers for each request but also did not find a way to do this.

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: I've no idea about that but someone did it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639691/ionic-ntlm-authentication-iis